# How to I find out the size of a GZIP section embedded in firmware?

Tags: java, size, gzip, compression

I am currently analyzing firmware images which contain many different sections, one of which is a GZIP section.

I am able to know the location of the start of the GZIP section using magic number and the `GZIPInputStream` in Java.

However, I need to know the **compressed** size of the gzip section. `GZIPInputStream` would return me the uncompressed file size.

Is there anybody who has an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can count the number of byte read using a custom InputStream. You would need to force the stream to read one byte at a time to ensure you don't read more than you need.

---

You can wrap your current InputStream in this

```
class CountingInputStream extends InputStream {
    final InputStream is;
    int counter = 0;

    public CountingInputStream(InputStream is) {
        this.is = is;
    }

    public int read() throws IOException {
        int read = is.read();
        if (read >= 0) counter++;
        return read;
    }
}
```

and then wrap it in a GZIPInputStream.  The field counter will hold the number of bytes read.

To use this with BufferedInputStream you can do

```
 InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
 // read some data or skip to where you want to start.

 CountingInputStream cis = new CountingInputStream(is);
 GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(cis);
 // read some compressed data
 cis.read(...);

 int dataRead = cis.counter;
```

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Could you suggest a way to create this custom inputStream? Currently, I am only using the GZIPInputStream and it is smart enough to know when the GZIP section ends.

Comment: sorry but would reading one byte at a time increase the number of file IOs significantly causing the program to run slowly for large files? thanks for the solution above btw. gonna try it now

Comment: @8to5, You are reading compressed data off firmware which is very advanced IMHO. I assumed you could count the number of times read() is called. ;)

Comment: @8to5, It would if you didn't use BufferedInputStream. ;)

Comment: haha.. something too advanced for me at the moment unfortunately. thanks for the help man. let know if i get it working

Comment: @8to5, Added how to use BufferedInputStream with this class. :P

Comment: @PeterLawrey what is ```dis``` in the code?

Comment: @Poli It should be cis

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is no easy way to tell the size of the gzipped data, other than just going through all the blocks.

gzip is a stream compression format, meaning that all the compressed data is written in a single pass. There is no way to stash the compressed size anywhere---it can't be in the header, since that would require more than one pass, and it's useless to have it at the trailer, since if you can locate the trailer, then you already know the compressed size.

Comment: Actually, it wouldn't be useless in the trailer. In retrospect, we should have put the compressed size in the trailer. gzip files can consist of multiple members, each of which is a valid gzip stream. A compressed size in the trailer of each member would permit scanning backwards from the end to quickly find the start of all of the members. That, combined with a longer uncompressed size field, would permit determining the uncompressed size of a gzip file very fast, without having to decompress it.